# "proxy_pass" directive is duplicate

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

Getting the error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mhprints:12
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

when trying to run my django project on nginx and gunicorn.

my settings in folder error points to:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 194.146.49.249;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/dave/mhprints;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Can't find a fix, hoping somebody knows on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, used the following command:

```
sudo grep -ri 'proxy_pass' /etc/nginx/
```

Found the duplicate and deleted it.